# Child index (1) must be less than the number of child elements

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Please forgive this basic question from a novice. I've been getting this error code sent to me on google apps script-

Child index (1) must be less than the number of child elements (0). (line 86, file "Code") ever since I changed some code.

There is no line 86 of the code and one test I ran suggests that enboldened line of code below is the problem.

Thanks in advance!

```
function getImageLinks(){
  //create array of images to update (paragraph, index, URL, width, height)
  var imgLocations = [
    [78,1,'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/EDITED OUTimage',680,393],

//  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1NENe-GSyUDNLHwp84cKwamDlQbbIipaZ2i2GGFUOFr0');  //test 
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1mwwJBPdGPAdILZ9pfARqTAG5Gt9svPthqZ8RcCRS6xI');  //prod
  var body = doc.getBody();
    for(var intX=0;intX<imgLocations.length;intX++){
      var newImage = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imgLocations[intX][2]);      
      var img = body.getChild(imgLocations[intX][0]).asParagraph().getChild(imgLocations[intX][1]);
      var parent = img.getParent();
      var paragraph = parent.asParagraph();
      img.removeFromParent();
      paragraph.insertInlineImage(imgLocations[intX][1],newImage);
      **var updatedImage = body.getChild(imgLocations[intX][**0]).asParagraph().getChild(imgLocations[intX][1]);
      updatedImage.asInlineImage().setWidth(imgLocations[intX][3]).setHeight(imgLocations[intX][4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: brackets: ```[[... ] ```

Comment: Did you truncate the code? imgLocations is lacking a closing bracket and is missing the last entry.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, bolding does not work in code formatting.

First of all as mentioned in the comments, you have open brackets here

```
var imgLocations = [
    [78,1,'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/EDITED OUTimage',680,393],
```

where it should be

```
var imgLocations = [
    [78,1,'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/EDITED OUTimage',680,393]]
```

note that not only you have missed a `]` but also have a `,` before the end, which indicates that your imgLocations should have more than 1 entry. Your `for` loop will only run over once, as `imgLocations.lenght` equals `1`

With that out of the way, the reason you are getting this problem coupled with lack of brackets is here:

```
var img = body.getChild(imgLocations[intX][0]).asParagraph().getChild(imgLocations[intX][1]);
```

as that will have 0 childs and you are expected to have at least 1 to get the parent.